# Don't want to use double quotes when using git commit -a -m

Tags: git, bash, shell

I'm a bit tired of using double quotation marks, when I use git commit

```
git commit -a -m "fix xxx error"
```

when I set alias like this:

```
coam = "!f() { git commit -a -m $1; }; f"
```

It works when I type

```
git coam fix
```

it commit as

```
git commit -a -m "fix"
```

but how to set a command which can handle

```
git commit -a -m "fix xxx error"
```

when I just type

```
git coam fix xxx error
```

I test

```
coam = "!f() { git commit -a -m $*; }; f"
```

but it doesn't work!

thanks!

Comment: You're so tired that you want to write a script to save you two keystrokes every time you commit ?

Comment: @PaulR ;-) letters are easy to find on the keyboard

Comment: Even though, one-liner commit messages are unhelpful in general, except when obvious. If you fix a bug, people would like to know what it was, why it was there and how you fixed it.

Comment: @HaveF, if you stick to using `"`, you'll learn to find it easily too, eventually! ;)

Comment: @fge thanks for your help! you are right, maybe I use the wrong example, it should be "git coam clean the code" ;-)

Comment: @PaulR you can save 16 keystrokes and moving left hand up to number row twice. `alias gitc="f() { git commit -a -m \"\$*\"; }; f"`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"I'm a bit tired of using double quotation marks," <-- but you don't have a choice.

This is how the shell works: it has mechanisms to make it so that if an argument contains characters that are normally input field separators (hint: that is why the `IFS` environment variable is named the way it is), it is still taken as an argument by the command which will be executed.

And `git commit`'s `-m` option takes a single argument. These double quotes are necessary.

The only way you can turn around that is to have your own little shell script which will gather these arguments for you:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec git commit -a -m "$*"
```

If the script above is called `mygitcm` and in your path, you may then do:

```
mygitcm my commit message here
```

Quoting your examples, I guess this would work:

```
coam = "!f() { git commit -a -m \"$*\"; }; f"
```

(another good idea would be to make explanative commit messages, of course ;))

Comment: alias coam="f() { git commit -a -m \"\$*\"; }; f"

Comment: Technically, aren't the quotes only needed for the spaces?

Answer (score 2):

```
function gc { git commit -a -m "$*"; }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is more useful to OP and future readers if you explain *why* and *how* the code works.

Comment: @mousetail I'm aware of that. I try to give better answers when I have time. This week isn't such a situation :) Perhaps someone can improve upon what little I provided.